# what does "off hold" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does "off hold" mean in the below sentence?

Are we able to *take Creation off hold* or still waiting for more payments?

Comment: I've tried to answer, but we really need more context, and in particular a complete source for this quote.  I assume it is from some TV show? Perhaps a comedy?

Comment: Thanks for your answer all the time and sorry for making you feel tired. James. I just saw the sentence from my coworkers this morning. by the way, I read your comments twice and have got your idea. thanks for your help. have a good day!!

Answer (score 3):

"Hold" is used to describe when a telephone call is paused from one side.  For example, if you call a business, you might be "put on hold" while the receptionist is busy.  When the receptionist is ready to talk to you, they will "take you off hold".

If something is "on hold" then it has to wait until we are ready for it. The use here with "Creation" (ie the universe as created by God) is metaphorical and probably a joke.  It's not possible to understand the intention of the joke without more context.